# What is a "new contributor" for Winter Bash purposes?

Tags: support, winter-bash, new-contributor-indicator

What is the combination of rep and timeline used to determine "*new contributor*" status?

Also, for sites with scaled-down rep requirements for badges, are those rep rep requirements scaled down the same way?

I'm interested in acquiring this hat, and wondering what sites I am eligible to try for it on.

[image]